# Overlapping animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

**Desirable result**
When clicking on one of the two images (id "kast1" and "kast2"), a highlight (.highlight_animatie_kast fadeIn and fadeOut) needs to start. By clicking on the highlight the image ("kast1") needs to move (animate) to the place of the highlight. Same goes for the other image ("kast2").

**Problem:**
When clicking on two images the shiny highlight animation overlaps, that causes another problem. The other problem is that (after clicked on both images) when clicking on the highlight the image wil move to the right but after that it moves again out of screen - probaply becuase of the overlapping highlight animations -.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m5dsjjku/34/)

jQuery:

```
    var isFadingIn1 = false
var isFadingIn2 = false

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".highlight_animatie_kast1").hide()
    $(".highlight_animatie_kast2").hide()

    function highlight1() {
        $('.highlight_animatie_kast1').fadeIn('slow')
        $('.highlight_animatie_kast1').fadeOut('slow', highlight1)
    }

    //1ste knop 

    $("#kast1").on("click", function () {
        if (!isFadingIn1) {
            isFadingIn1 = true
            $('.fadeToggleKastje1').addClass("fadeToggleActief")  
            $(".highlight_animatie_kast2").hide()
            $('.highlight_animatie_kast2').stop(true, true)

            if (isFadingIn2){
                $('.fadeToggleKastje2').removeClass("fadeToggleActief")
                $('.fadeToggleKastje1').addClass("fadeToggleActief")  
                $(".highlight_animatie_kast2").hide()
                $('.highlight_animatie_kast2').stop(true, true)
            }

            var $highlight1 = $(".highlight_animatie_kast1")
            $highlight1.one("click", function () {

                  var imageDiv = $( "#kast1" )

                  imageDiv.children("img").animate({
                      right: '+=270px'
                  }, 1500 )      
            })

            $highlight1.fadeToggle("slow", function () {
                $('.highlight_animatie_kast1').fadeIn('slow')
                $('.highlight_animatie_kast1').fadeOut('slow', highlight1)
            })

        } else {
            $('.highlight_animatie_kast1').stop(true, true)
            $(".highlight_animatie_kast1").hide()
            isFadingIn1 = false  
            $('.fadeToggleKastje1').removeClass("fadeToggleActief")
        }
    })

    //2de knop 

    function highlight2() {
        $('.highlight_animatie_kast2').fadeIn('slow')
        $('.highlight_animatie_kast2').fadeOut('slow', highlight2)
    }

    $("#kast2").on("click", function () {
        if (!isFadingIn2) {
            isFadingIn2 = true
            $('.fadeToggleKastje2').addClass("fadeToggleActief")
            $(".highlight_animatie_kast2").hide()
            $('.highlight_animatie_kast1').stop(true, true)

            if (isFadingIn1){
                $('.fadeToggleKastje1').removeClass("fadeToggleActief")                                                   
                $('.fadeToggleKastje2').addClass("fadeToggleActief") 
                $(".highlight_animatie_kast1").hide()
                $('.highlight_animatie_kast1').stop(true, true)
            }

            var $highlight2 = $(".highlight_animatie_kast2")

            $highlight2.one("click", function () {

                  var imageDiv = $( "#kast2" )

                  imageDiv.children("img").animate({
                      right: '+=180px'
                  }, 1500 )
            })

            $highlight2.fadeToggle("slow", function () {
                $('.highlight_animatie_kast2').fadeIn('slow')
                $('.highlight_animatie_kast2').fadeOut('slow', highlight2)
            })

        } else {
            $('.highlight_animatie_kast2').stop(true, true)
            $(".highlight_animatie_kast2").hide()
            isFadingIn2 = false
            $('.fadeToggleKastje2').removeClass("fadeToggleActief")
        }
    })     

})
```

CSS:

```
  div {
      border: 1px solid yellow;
  }

  #highlight_posities {
      position: absolute;
      width: 280px;
      height: 200px;
      padding: 25px 20px 20px 100px;
      border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  }
  #eersteRijKast{
      position: relative;  
      top:20px;
      right:90px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 80px;
  }  
  .highlight_animatie_kast1 {
      position: relative;
      top: 30%;
      left: -7%;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      font-size: 36px;
      background: yellow;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 20px yellow;
  }
  .highlight_animatie_kast2 {
      position: relative;
      top: 30%;
      left: -7%;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      font-size: 36px;
      background: yellow;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 20px yellow;
  }

  #kast1 {
      position:relative;
      top:20px;  
  }

  #kast2 {
      position:relative;
      top:20px;
  }

  .fadeToggleKastje1 {
      position:relative;
      float: right;
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;   
  }
  .fadeToggleKastje2  {
      position:relative;
      float: right;
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;    
  }

  .image {
      position:relative;
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px; 
  }

  .fadeToggleActief {
      background-color:"yellow";
      border: 5px solid yellow;
  }
```

I am aware that the code isn't that stable, but I hope it could be fixed with few changes.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: It's possible that the issue is caused by page re-flow when `.fadeout()` completes. As the documetation says, "once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none". You could try `.amimate('opacity', 1)` and `.amimate('opacity', 0)` instead of `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`.

Comment: Why `stop(true, true)`? The second `true` means "jump to end and fire the callback". Since the callback is a recursion of the animation effect, `.stop(true, true)` will surely cause nothing more than a glitch. `stop(true, false)` seems more appropriate.

Comment: The images that are animated with `right: '+=180px'` will only move in one direction unless something causes them to move in the other direction or resets them to their original position. That code is not present.

Comment: The image still shifts to the highlight and then out of the screen, probably because the overlapping. Thanks

Comment: I need to see this live. Can you post a link to a demo please, preferably a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Here is the JSfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/zfut5e6a/2/
It happens when switching from image to image before you click on the animated highlight.

Comment: @K, I see the highlight effect but nothing else - no movement, no overlap. (Opera under Win 7).

Comment: Click a few times on the highlight, more in the middle of animation. I use FireFox and Chrome (Mac).

Comment: This is probably a better version: http://jsfiddle.net/zfut5e6a/5/

Comment: I agree, it's not correct. To fix it, I would need a properly drafted Requirement Spec and would probably choose to rewrite the code from scratch.